# What is the meaning of "I have no ear for languages"?

Tags: meaning

In English Crime-Drama movie *Ghost Dog: The Way of the Samurai (1999*), Ice Cream seller French guy called Raymond said this words
to English speaking girl, Pearline, in French:

> Do you speak any French? Because if you did, it would be much easier
>   for me to learn English. I took a course, but damn it was too hard.
>   Maybe **I have no ear for languages**.

Comment: [have an ear for](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+an+ear+for). "I have no ear for languages" would be the same as "I don't *have an ear* for languages".

Comment: It could also mean an inability to distinguish languages from one another. I have had to frequently explain to my friends the nationality of an author I thought was self-evident (I had to explain to 3 people in a row Dostoevsky was Russian and not German as they had 'no ear for languages' and couldn't distinguish between Russian and German).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an idiomatic expression that means Raymond is not good at learning languages.    The image is that his "ears" aren't very good at understanding the unfamiliar sounds.